# OracleDataAdapter.Fill gives error after issuing DROP COLUMN

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am using ODP.NET (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) to run a query on an Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 database with a pluggable database.  I am encountering an error when I use OracleDataAdapter right after dropping a column.  The error is "ORA-01007: variable not in select list".

The problem only occurs when I:

1. Create and use an OracleDataAdapter (select *)
2. Drop a column from the table
3. Create and use another OracleAdapter (select *)

It's like it is caching the columns (I am using select * for the command).  Does anyone know if ODP.net driver does some kind of internal caching like this and whether I can clear it?

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

using(var con = new OracleConnection(TestConnectionStrings[DatabaseType.Oracle]))
{
    con.Open();

    //OracleCommand drop = new OracleCommand("DROP TABLE RaceTable2", con);
    //drop.ExecuteNonQuery();

    OracleCommand create = new OracleCommand("CREATE TABLE RaceTable2 ( A int NOT NULL, B int NOT NULL, C int NOT NULL, D int NOT NULL, E int NOT NULL)",con);
    create.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var da = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from RaceTable2",con);
    da.Fill(dt1);

    OracleCommand dropCol = new OracleCommand("ALTER TABLE RaceTable2 DROP COLUMN E", con);
    dropCol.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var da2 = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from RaceTable2", con);
    da2.Fill(dt2); //crashes on this line
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a new connection for the `SELECT…` after the `DROP...`?

Comment: I would guess that the `con` has kept a record of which columns returned previously and got confused when the second query didn't return some.  As @stuartd suggests, a new connection would probably help.

Comment: Just tried using a fresh connection for the second select *, no change in behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think it might be related to [Implicit Statement Caching](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/stmtcach.htm#i1069942).  I added a call to PurgeStatementCache after the ALTER and this seemed to fix it:

```
con.PurgeStatementCache();
```

I can only assume that this is held server side since even opening a new connection for the second select* didn't work.

Either that or it is a time based thing and the call just kills some time on the server.